# Not ask user permission to access camera in other languages than English

Tags: ios, xcode, camera

My app isn't asking user permission to access camera or photo library when settings language isn't English. Only works if Settings language is English. How to fix it? (I include in info.plist NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and NSCameraUsageDescription to support IOS 10 ) When I reset privacy I need to change language to English then launch the app and it works ok asking for permission, but if language is other then English the problem occurs. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer : Bundle display name , missing name in info.plist file. Worked ok after entered app name in this field. Don't forget to use localizations NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and NSCameraUsageDescription in info.Plist.strings